# CSS: how to keep my text fixed wrt to window size?

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I want my text not to move when I resize the window as it happens with the image.

I tried using a `<div>` container with a `left` attribute among other things however I am unable to achieve the result I'm looking for.

I have the following CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #204f6e;
    background-image: asset-url('beige_paper.png');
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
#div1 {
    visibility:show;
    left: 606px;
    top: 59px;
    z-index:200;
}
.image1 {
    height: 9.65em;
}
#div2 {
    visibility:show;
    left: 187px;
    top: 218px;
    z-index:200;
}
#div3 {
    visibility:show;
    left: 185px;
    top: 305px;
    right: 200px;
    z-index:200;
}
#div4 {
    visibility:show;
    left: 215px;
    top: 390px;
    right: 200px;
    z-index:200;
}
```

and I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <%=i mage_tag( "logo.png", :class=>"image1") %>
</div>

<br />

<div class="contents" id="div2">
     <h1>
         <p>
             <span style="color: #008080;">
                 <strong>
                     <span style="font-size: 60px;">Some text</span>
                 </strong>
             </span>
         </p>
     </h1>
</div>

<div class="contents" id="div3">
    <p> 
        <span style="font-size: 11px; color: #808080;">
            <span style="font-size: 30px;">
                Some text
            </span>
            <br />
        </span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="contents" id="div4">
    <p> 
        <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #808080;">
            Some text
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54yMU/)

Comment: `visibility:show;` should be `visibility:visible;`.

Comment: What do you mean you don't want the text to move?

Comment: i dont want text to be affected while resizing. like if i shrink the window it shold not come on the other line rather it should move in the same line with a horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` on the element for which you don't want the text to wrap.

Comment: i have edited my question. i have uploaded a fiddle use that. thanx.

Comment: I have updated my answer, not sure why I thought `text-wrap` was supported.

Comment: I'm not sure what restore button you are talking about. I have applied the rule to the `body` element in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54yMU/2/).

Comment: i mean the button which is present before close button in our browser

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't very clear, but there are a few ways to go.

### Static widths

You could use a static width for an element. For instance:

```
html { width: 1200px; }
```

will make your entire page always be 1200px wide. Substitute `html` for any element, ID or class you want.

### Nowrap

If you want a block element to not do text wrapping at all, you can use `white-space`:

```
h1 { white-space: nowrap; }
```

The example above would make all level 1 headings print on one line, no matter how wide they are.

### Also...

...not really related to the question, but your HTML is all messed up and makes it harder for you. There is no reason to nest the `<span>` tags the way you do, for instance, and a `<p>` should never be nested inside an `<h1>` tag. And why use `<strong>` there? An extra strong heading? You will find that keeping your HTML neat and clean will help a great deal when writing your CSS.